# The Joule Thief is what kind of oscillator? Armstrong? Relaxation? or what? Thanks!

Tags: oscillator, joule-thief

On Wikipedia, the [Joule Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief) is described as being an [Armstrong oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_oscillator), which I strongly believe it is not (because it has no capacitor).  But the Wikipedia article tries to back up this statement by citing a scholarly article, ["Fun Examples for Teaching Linear and Nonlinear Circuits"](http://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1173865/1173865.pdf) which states that the Joule Thief is an Armstrong oscillator.  Please state why the Joule Thief is NOT an Armstrong oscillator, what kind it really is, and why.  (Even if it really is an Armstrong, then I'll be satisfied.)  If this is a mistake up on Wikipedia, then perhaps we can fix it and cite this page along with justification for changing it to a "relaxation oscillator", or whatever it really is.

Comment: It really is a joule thief. Or let's call it Clive oscillator. But really, why does it matter?

Comment: @Neil_UK how many times has a question on this fair site been retrospectively altered and thus invalidated answers previously given and, how many times has this caused aggro. Well now you have taken this to the ultimate by invalidating a question LOL\$^2\$.

Comment: @Andyaka Reverted in only 20 minutes. They don't like engineering, they call it original research, which is not permitted. Ho hum.

Comment: @PlasmaHH -- The truth always matters, because truth can be a foundation.  People who try to build a Joule Thief and follow directions from the Armstrong oscillator section will be confused and probably fail.  Is there an absolute truth?  If you say no, you've said "there is no absolute truth, except for one, and that is ... that it is absolutely true that there are no absolute truths." This inherent contradiction disproves the statement that there are no absolute truths.  So we should all be truth-finders, should we not?

Comment: Wikipedia is only there to give an overview about real sources. It contains lots of nonsense, if you care about truth there, it is a lost battle, they collect what others write without reflection. When you build an oscillator, besides not following a wikipedia page, you should not follow some whatever oscillator but understand how it works and build on that understand, no matter what its name is. These names are just to easier talk about things to not have to describe them before you get the idea what it is about

Comment: Wikipedia fixed. Bringing truth to the internet, one page at a time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Joule Thief, at least the classic 'Clive' Joule Thief, clearly isn't an Armstrong.

An Armstrong oscillator uses very light coupling between two inductors (it's often called a 'tickler' for this very reason) with one of the inductors in parallel with a capacitor to define the frequency.

The 'Clive' Joule Thief uses two strongly coupled inductors (aka a transformer), and no capacitor. The frequency is defined by the relaxation behaviour between the supply voltage, the value of the primary inductor, and the threshhold currents of the transistor to come out of saturation.

Wikipedia has now been corrected. The publication used to support the assertion that the oscillator is Armstrong,  ["Fun Examples for Teaching Linear and Nonlinear Circuits", Circuits and Systems (ISCAS), 2013 IEEE International Symposium on, 19–23 May 2013, p2557 - 2560](http://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1173865/1173865.pdf) quoted the Wikipedia Joule Thief article as its authority. A circular reference like that is obviously not reliable.

Comment: Oscillators are not my bread and butter, so please take my question as honest curiosity, but... when you say "and the threshold currents of the transistor in order to come out of saturation", should you not take into account the fact that there is a hidden capacity to discharge before coming out of saturation?

Comment: @SredniVashtar All circuits have some stray capacity. However, it's the difference between a few pFs which has to be  incidentally charged as well while other things happen, and a component of a few nF or uF which is put there to dominate the behaviour. A blocking oscillator ends its conduction phase when the collector current tries to exceed beta x base current, so stops increasing, so removes feedback. This is slightly affected by stray capacity. An Armstrong operates in a more linear manner, with LC resonance controlling the frequency.

Comment: The wikipedia way is to flag the word *Armstrong* with a [Citation needed], wait for six month, use the discussion page, then remove it as not proven.

Comment: Ah, I see, they have a source, which is obviously wrong on this thing. Funny enough, de.wikipedia says the Joule thief is a relaxation oscillator.

Comment: What I meant is that the "coming out of saturation" is mostly due to removing charges from the base of the transistor. So, the presence of that capacitor is not just a 'side effect' but it actually is the mechanism that make the transistor go into deep saturation. I do agree that its effect can be very minor wrt to the overall period of oscillation. It appears there are three mechanism at work here: how long does it take to move from cutoff to saturation, how long does it take for the core to saturate, and how long does it take to move out of deep saturation...

Comment: ... I have yet to see a full quantitative discussion of a Joule thief, one that would make it possible to predict its frequency of oscillation. I simulated a few, and noticed that the frequency can be appreciably changed by simply choosing a different BJT. The spike in ib takes up a very minor portion of the period of oscillation.

Comment: @Neil_UK I have more trust in the quality of toilet paper than w***pedia...

Comment: @SredniVashtar The fact that 'coming out of saturation' is due to 'removing charges from the base', which latter phrase uses the word 'charges', and capacitors handle 'charge' is one of those 'true, but irrelevant' things. It comes out of saturation because the collector/base current ratio passes a threshhold. As you say, oscillators are not your bread and butter. I'm not going to argue the toss about whether the frequency is 'mostly' determined by the LC product, or by the voltage+inductance+transistor characteristics. You'll come to make those judgements with experience.

Comment: I wasn't challenging your classification of the circuit, I just thought some clarification was in order. Your wording made it appear that the lack of a capacitance was enough to rule out it being Armstrong, when a capacitance is there after all. As I said, my simulations of a vanilla JT appear to confirm that the role of that capacitance is really minor: moreover, the exponential rise and decay of the inductor current fit that of a relaxation oscillator. But, it all depends on the circuit: there are JT with no coupling between inductors and a capacitor that make the oscillation possible.

Comment: @SredniVashtar When is a horse a zebra? I'm sure it's possible to continuously vary the capacitance and the coupling to vary between a classic tightly coupled no-capacitor JT, and a lightly coupled LC Armstrong, and wring some sort of oscillation out of each. However, that only muddies the waters. Capacitance will always alter the frequency of a JT, and coupling will always alter the frequency of an Armstrong. To make the identification, we assume ideal behaviour, and contrast the two bounds.

Comment: No, no, I'm not talking about the "vanilla Joule Thief" with some more stray capacitance. But a different topology that does the same thing (boost the voltage of the battery and produces oscillations) where the cap plays a dominant role. (From the simulation, the frequency appears to be twice that of the tank circuit - I only simulated it, maybe someday I'll put it on a breadboard or solder it). So, I guess the controversy on the classification of Joule Thieves can be blamed on the different topologies that are called "Joule Thief". There are also variants with two transistors...

Comment: @SredniVashtar If you're talking about a different Joule Thief, then it will be different. Duh! Let's talk about the classic 'Clive' JT, and then other different circuits that work from an interestingly low voltage, with a surprisingly low number of components. Are we on the same page yet?

Comment: @Janka Thanks for your cool head. I've flagged the reference as circular.

Comment: The problem is that the term Joule Thief is used to describe many topologies. Wikipedia is a dynamic multi-author document, so the people who wrote the Armstrong reference is most likely not the same people who added the schematics, and perhaps other parts of that entry have been added by people who do not even know who Big Clive is, so they do not know that he just invented the name, not the circuit. Today, the name is used for many topologies, so an answer to a question "what kind of oscillator is the Joule Thief" should address this ambiguity.

Comment: @SredniVashtar I'm sure if you polled many engineers and asked what a JT was, they'd overwhelmingly vote for the Kaparnik/Mitchell topology, as published in 1999 EPE, with no capacitor. You are welcome to your variants.

Answer (score 2):

It is a relaxation oscillator which is not a type of circuit but a description of its behavior.

> The circuit consists of a feedback loop containing a switching device such as a **transistor**, comparator, relay, op amp, or a negative resistance device like a tunnel diode, that repetitively charges a capacitor or **inductor** through a resistance until it reaches a **threshold level**, then discharges it again.

In the case of the joule thief the transformer is charged (with flux) through the transistor until the flux stops increasing then discharged through the load.

Comment: So is it an Armstrong?  And exactly what is your Quote from?  Would you please clarify your answer.  Thank you.

Comment: It is not an Armstrong oscillator. The Armstrong oscillator is a linear or harmonic oscillator.

Comment: It is not really a transformer, though.  A transformer puts power into one winding, and gets power out of the other winding.  This is a coupled-inductor where one winding is (or should be) a power inductor, and the second winding is really a sense winding that only recieves the small amount of current to drive the transistor.  The sense winding can be very fine wire -- just reduce the resistance of the resistor to which it is attached.